# How to skip Flutter Widget in tap detection?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a modal bottom sheet with `ListTile`s that contain a `Checkbox` as the leading widget. However, the `Checkbox` will receive tap event instead of the `ListTile`, now showing the ink ripple effect for the tile and making me implement two `onTap`/`onChanged` callbacks.

I have tried not implementing the `Checkbox`'s `onChanged` callback and wrapping it around an `AbsorbPointer` widget, however in these two cases the `ListTile` would also not get the tap event.

```dart
return ListTile(
  onTap: onTap,
  title: Text("Show expired schedules"),
  leading: Checkbox(value: snapshot.data, onChanged: (_) => onTap()),
);
```

I would like to somehow make the `Checkbox` not tappable, but have the `ListTile` still receive the tap event. Kind of like `AbsorbPointer`, except skipping one Widget, not absorbing the tap event entirely.

Comment: I'd still love to hear the correct answer, but if you are in a tight pinch, you could always remove the checkbox and just use an icon and change the icon in code. checked unchecked.  ?

Comment: @Zuriel The `Checkbox` has an animation when the value changes and it's just easier to implement than having two separate icons

Comment: Why not just remove the `onChange`?

Comment: I guess because removing onChange method will use the disabledColor from Theme for the Checkbox.

Comment: @Rémi Rousselet @diegoveloper Yes, it will use the disabledColor and also still absorb the touch event, not passing it on to the `ListTile`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your `Checkbox` widget inside `IgnorePointer` widget and it should work:

```
return ListTile(
  onTap: onTap,
  title: Text("Show expired schedules"),
  leading: IgnorePointer(child: Checkbox(value: snapshot.data, onChanged: (_) => onTap())),
);
```

Comment: Thank you! They should have included this one too in the Widget of the Week for AbsorbPointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `AbsorbPointer` too

```
return ListTile(
  onTap: onTap,
  title: Text("Show expired schedules"),
  leading: AbsorbPointer(
    absorbing: _condition, // bool value, true makes it absorb touch event on CheckBox still making ListTile tappable. 
    child: Checkbox(value: snapshot.data, onChanged: (_) => onTap()),
  ),
);
```